# IE 10 and jQuery 1.10.2 getting 0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013

I have a web application using jQuery.Ajax to get JSON data from the service layer. I am getting the following error in the .done of the Ajax call (not the .fail).

0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

The line of code generating the error is:

```
var a = JSON.parse(result.d);
```

The data coming back is in perfect JSON format when viewed in the debugger:

```
[{"name":"Admin"},{"name":"SuperUser"}]
```

I am seeing a lot of wavelength on this error when googling around but no resolutions. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us the .done portion of your ajax call? and the datatype and response headers (contentType specifically)

Comment: If your responseText is `[{"name":"Admin"},{"name":"SuperUser"}]`, why are you using `result.d` instead of just `result`? I don't see a `d` property on `result`

Answer (score 0):

I recently received this same error and traced it back to an invalid character in the SQL server table that the web service was reading from.  In the debugger, this character showed up as a space but was in fact a unicode character (0x28 in this case).  After removing the character from the db, I didn't get the error any more.   Time to buff up my input verification to make sure these values don't get saved to the db anymore!  :)

Answer (score -2):

I handle my results in the success part of $.ajax

```
    $.ajax({
    url: serviceurl,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(responseText) {
   //responseText is already a JSON object so you can access its properties directly
   //not that I encourage that :p
  if(responseText.length>0)
   {
       //do something with the array
   }
  },
 complete: function (){
 console.log('ajax complete');
},
error: function() {
  console.log('ajax error');
}
});
```

Comment: .done replaces success in the newer versions of jQuery

Comment: As you can see I'm not chaining functions, and jQuery still lists success to handle a successful ajax operation.

Comment: My point is that this code returns to the .done branch - not the .fail but then throws the error.